# In CSS how to get three containers automatically resize height based on content

Tags: html, css

What I have is three containers with dynamically added content. Basically I want those three rows to take up the height of the browser window only. But I want them to resize automatically based on their inner content.

So if they all have the same amount of content, each of them have a height of about 33% and then an overflow: auto.  Or if one container has no content and the other two have lots of content the container with no content should have a height of 0 and the other two should be 50%.

Also, there is no need to support IE - it's for an internal product and only chrome and firefox browsers are used so if there is a css3 solution then that is okay.

So here is the example of what I have now which **doesn't work** how I want:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="one">
     <!-- dynamically added content -->
    </div>

    <div class="two">
     <!-- dynamically added content -->
    </div>

     <div class="three">
     <!-- dynamically added content -->
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 33%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Height is automatically set based on content. You have a max-height set so you'll never get a height of 50%. Does the container element need to say one size or can it change with content?

Comment: Basically the height needs to be some "magical value" which is auto and proportional and doesn't give space to the containers with no content. So yes setting a height to any fixed value is wrong, but if I don't set a height it the content goes outside the screen height. If there isn't a way and I need to use JavaScript so be it.

Comment: Is the 3rd div the one that will not have content is there is no content? You could do .one,two { max-height:50%;} .one,.two,.three{overflow:auto} so when three had no content, 1 and 2 would expand to 50%

Comment: No - any of them could have no content or a massive amount. I don't know what will be in there because the content is produced dynamically.